# How to set array state in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, setstate

I have an array in my state and I want to set array specific values to its objects.
The code looks like this:

```
 state = {
      course: "",
      type: "",
      days: [
              {
                day: "",
                rstime: "",
                retime: "",
              }
            ],
        }

  createSchedule = () => {
          const { course,
                  module,
                  days
                } = this.state;

          data.push({
                  course,
                  module,
                  days[]
                  })
  }
```

For now, I am able to set the state of course and module. I want to know how to set the days so that a course can have multiple days and different times.

The output should look like this for instance:

```
Course: Biology
Type: Lecture
days: 
      {
        Monday
        09:30
        11:40
      } 
      {
        Friday
        15:30
        16:40
      }
```

Comment: what u mean without affect previous state, you want the previous state with this new values ? or not want to render again for this update of the data ?

Comment: I mean like when you have put the first day and its starting and end time, you can put different days with a different time and the first day should not be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can something like this,

```
const days = [...this.state.days];

days.push({
        Friday
        15:30
        16:40
      });

this.setState({days});
```